# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning animate preferedContentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Suppose I have a `UINavigationController` that is presented as a popover. It has its delegate refer to a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` class when transitioning between views:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return AnimationController(presenting: (operation==.push)
}
```

However, views being pushed have different preferred content sizes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.preferredContentSize = self.preferredContentSize
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.preferredContentSize = self.preferredContentSize
    }
}
```

Currently, when I push a view controller onto the stack, I see my custom animation execute, followed by a change of the popover size. How can I resize the popover concurrently with my animation running? Setting the `preferedContentSize` or adjusting constraints from within `animateTransition(using: ...)` seems to have no effect.

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else { return }
        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toView)
        toView.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toView.alpha = 1.0
        }) { _ in
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            if !success {
                toView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }
    }
```